# Frequent reports of jgroups dropped messages during a performance test

Tags: multicast, jgroups

Jgroup version : 3.4.4

Config :

```
UDP(mcast_addr=228.6.7.8;mcast_port=22222;ip_ttl=8;mcast_send_buf_size=150000;mcast_recv_buf_size=80000):PING(timeout=2000;num_initial_members=3):MERGE2(min_interval=5000;max_interval=10000):FD_SOCK:VERIFY_SUSPECT(timeout=1500):pbcast.NAKACK(gc_lag=50;retransmit_timeout=300,600,1200,2400,4800):UNICAST(timeout=5000):pbcast.STABLE(desired_avg_gossip=20000):FRAG(frag_size=4096;down_thread=false;up_thread=false):pbcast.GMS(join_timeout=5000;join_retry_timeout=2000;shun=false;print_local_addr=false):pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER
```

During a performance test(four node JGroup cluster) frequent reports (WARN severity) of dropped / failed messages from jgroups.

These reports also occasionally occur during traffic (and even sometimes when idle).

WARN messages :

```
WARN [tid=bpsp-XYZ01-150615142241421-618331378-0-2] [bpsp-XYZ01-4296] org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2 - JGRP000011: bpsp-XYZ01-4296: dropped message 330 from non-member bpsp-XYZ03-31792 (view=[bpsp-XYZ02-58715|3260] (15) [bpsp-XYZ02-58715, bpsp-XYZ04-33866, bpsp-XYZ04-35133, bpsp-XYZ01-1551, bpsp-XYZ02-17088, bpsp-XYZ02-2701, bpsp-XYZ02-50162, bpsp-XYZ02-19697, bpsp-XYZ01-8027, bpsp-XYZ01-32523, bpsp-XYZ01-4296, bpsp-XYZ01-10112, bpsp-XYZ04-10116, bpsp-XYZ04-48624, bpsp-XYZ04-16847])
WARN [tid=bpsp-XYZ01-150615142241421-618331378-0-1b] [bpsp-XYZ01-28987] org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2 - JGRP000011: bpsp-XYZ01-28987: dropped message 1447 from non-member bpsp-XYZ03-54278 (view=[bpsp-XYZ02-33248|3071] (3) [bpsp-XYZ02-33248, bpsp-XYZ01-28987, bpsp-XYZ04-38112])
WARN [tid=bpsp-XYZ01-150615142241421-618331378-0-2a] [bpsp-XYZ01-46462] org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2 - JGRP000011: bpsp-XYZ01-46462: dropped message 4146 from non-member bpsp-XYZ03-39195 (view=[bpsp-XYZ04-59688|3045] (3) [bpsp-XYZ04-59688, bpsp-XYZ01-46462, bpsp-XYZ02-14036])
WARN [tid=bpsp-XYZ01-150615142241421-618331378-0-5] [XYZ01-34208] org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS - bpsp-XYZ01-34208: failed to collect all ACKs (expected=3) for view [bpsp-XYZ03-20005|3047] after 2000ms, missing 1 ACKs from bpsp-XYZ02-33303
WARN [tid=bpsp-XYZ01-150615142241421-618331378-0-12] [bpsp-XYZ01-36922] org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2 - JGRP000011: bpsp-XYZ01-36922: dropped message 541 from non-member bpsp-XYZ02-55864 (view=[bpsp-XYZ04-32626|3097] (3) [bpsp-XYZ04-32626, bpsp-XYZ01-36922, bpsp-XYZ03-58090])
```

Appreciate your idea on this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your network infrastructure can handle the perf-test traffic?
You can also check your server's CPU/memory usage as sometimes the server is busy, so even if the traffic arrives it can't handle it due to CPU exhaustion.

Comment: Good points. We have a gigabit network. Didn't observe any network or CPU exhaustion. But I think I need to look further.